# Should I continue answering a frequent poster that consistently accepts my answers?

Tags: discussion

Over the past month or two a user has been frequently posting questions and I, for want of a real life, have been posting reviews to most of them.

However the user seams to be predominately accepting my answers above others (it's like free rep points).

I would just like to know if this could be a problem?

I don't mind answering and he seems eager to learn and picks up on the points given in most of the answers. Unlike some where you get the feeling you are talking to a wall and hence don't bother answering.

Comment: Why do you think that the poster prefers *your answer* instead of *the best answer*?

Comment: @Vogel612 I believe my answers are the best answers.

Comment: then what is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have been in similar situations a couple of times in the past. There's nothing wrong with it, I only caution you not to be taken for granted...

- you have no obligation to answer their questions - only answer if you want to
- feel free to ignore requests for additional details, explanations, etc.
- remember that the site works on Q&A where questions are in posts, not comments, and anyone can answer.

So, that's my only caution - to remember that you are answering questions to satisfy your own motivations... whatever those may be. If you fall in to the trap of answering questions to satisfy other people's needs/demands, then you'll not have the "fun" this site should be. It should not be a "chore" (and there have been times in the past where the site has felt like a chore - so I speak from experience when I recommend caution).

Having cautioned you for the traps, the upside is that if you establish a sequence of answers you can really see the positive impacts you can have on other people's learning, and it is very satisfying when you feel you have helped someone like that. The reputation/internet points are a bonus (well deserved, but still just a bonus).

Comment: I have been posting online since the days of BBS and can easily ignore demanding users. I was more concerned that it may raise some automated flags? For now I will keep doing as I have done.

Comment: @Blindman67 If this raises flags, I wonder how many I've created by only voting on Python questions and answers, with a not so large answerer pool ;P

Comment: @Peilonrayz and Blindman67 - no automated flags have been created (yet).... but it made me look in to voting patterns against your account (the tools used to look for sock-puppets), and there is a distinct "correlation" between your accounts (you probably vote for the questions, and your answers get voted up too). But, there's nothing suspicious in there.